# How to disable the interface orientation change in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiinterfaceorientation

Interface orientation support is enabled in my .plist file. But I need to enable landscape orientation only in one viewController. In other viewControllers I can't disable landscape mode. Please, tell me how I can disable landscape mode in all viewControllers except one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; 
  //return here which orientation you are going to support 

}
```

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. No matter what I set the supported interface orientation to, it always allows rotation anyway. And supportedInterfaceOrientations is even getting called! shouldAutorotate never gets called.